# Javascript replace expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble replacing some url variables in javascript. I'm trying to replace the value of `&s=` and `&so=`. Below is my code:

```
url = url.replace(/(s=).*?(&)/, '$1' + $("#sort_by").val() + '$2');
url = url.replace(/(so=).*?(&)/, '$1' + $("#sort_ord").val() + '$2');
```

The first replace works no problem, the `s` value is always replaced, but the `so` variable never seems to get replaced.

Comment: Could you give an example url?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you wanna do this? Seems wrong to me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
url = url.replace(/(s=)[^&]*/, '$1' + $("#sort_by").val());
url = url.replace(/(so=)[^&]*/, '$1' + $("#sort_ord").val());
```

This should work with most URL (but not all URL as allowed by the RFC). This takes advantage of the fact that `&` is mostly used to delimit key-value pair in the query string of the URL.

Comment: `(&?)` or `(&|$)` for that matter ;)

Comment: @poncha: There is also the possibility of fragment (although it is rare to see it together with query) in the URL. It fails either way.

Comment: they are always "&" (fixed url structure) - tried changing and it still didn't work :(

Comment: @nhahtdh then need `([#&]|$)` to be precise ;)

Comment: My answer was wrong on multiple levels (see edit history). This final edits gives at least the right facts with tested code.